# How to use a resource collection toArray and DB (without Eloquent)

Tags: php, laravel

I have this query (in a repository, without using Eloquent):

```
    public function getUsersOfASchool($schoolId, $request)
    {

        $query = DB::table('school_users as su')
            ->join('users as u', 'u.id', 'su.user_id')
            ->where('su.school_id', $schoolId);

        $users = $query->paginate();

        return $users;
    }
```

I have this controller:

```
try{
        $users = $this->userRepository->getUsersOfASchool($school->id, $request->all());
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Bad request '.$e->getMessage()], 400);
    }

    return new UserCollection($users);
```

And at least, I have this collection:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return parent::toArray($request);
}
```

I have this error 500:

> "message": "Call to undefined method stdClass::toArray()",

I think it is because I use the 'DB' facade instead of Eloquent. So how to work with 'DB' facade and collection?

Comment: please check bettere where the "toArray" function is called... nowhere in the code you have posted, that function is executed, so probably you are missundestanding the functions which are executed in the flow

Comment: Please post that code where you have called the `toArray($data)` function?

Comment: try like this: `return new UserCollection(collect($users));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because **query builder** return a collection with stdClass inside.

And **ResourceCollection**'s method `toArray` will map the collection, then run the `toarray()` on stdClass. So error occurs.

However, eloquent builder collection will map the collection, run the `toArray()` on model's object. And this object has `toArray()` method.

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Http/Resources/Json/ResourceCollection.php#L57):

```php
    /**
     * Transform the resource into a JSON array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return $this->collection->map->toArray($request)->all();
    }
```

So you can rewrite the `toArray()` method for query builder in your resource:

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    // return parent::toArray($request);

    $collection = $this->collection;
    if (method_exists($collection->map, 'toArray')) {
        return $collection->map->toArray($request)->all();
    } else {
        // for stdClass
        return json_decode(json_encode($collection, true), true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi TsaiKoga, Thanks a lot for your complete answer. It s clear now for me and it works fine with your solution. However, the use of resource was a test for me and I am not convinced , I think I will give up the resource and use a traditional "return a model" in a json. Thanks again for your help. Dom