# laravel api resource collection with row query

Tags: laravel, collections, resources

```
$two = DB::select("SELECT
                ul.id ,
                ul.name controller_name, 
                ul.user_id controller_user_id,
                ul.location contoller_location, 
                u.name user_name,
                models.active model_alive_status,
                models.serial_number model_sirial_number,
                su.payment_status subscriptions_status,
                su.to_date subscriptions_expire
    FROM `user_controllers` as ul
    LEFT JOIN users as u ON ul.user_id = u.id
    INNER JOIN models on models.userController_id = ul.id
    LEFT join subscriptions as su on su.user_id = ul.user_id");

return UserControllerInfo::collection($two);
```

this gives me an error like

> "message": "Call to undefined method stdClass::toArray()",

```
$one = DB::table('user_controllers')
        ->leftJoin('users', 'user_controllers.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->leftJoin('models', 'models.userController_id', '=', 'user_controllers.id')
        ->leftJoin('subscriptions', 'subscriptions.user_id', '=', 'user_controllers.user_id')
        ->select('user_controllers.*','models.*')
        ->get();
```

this also same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a resource collection toArray and DB (without Eloquent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60019662/how-to-use-a-resource-collection-toarray-and-db-without-eloquent)

Comment: @Sehdev no these two are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query builder will return the collection with stdClass,
try to change Query Builder to Eloquent Builder:

```php
$one = UserController::leftJoin('users', 'user_controllers.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                     ->leftJoin('models', 'models.userController_id', '=', 'user_controllers.id')
                     ->leftJoin('subscriptions', 'subscriptions.user_id', '=', 'user_controllers.user_id')
                     ->select('user_controllers.*','models.*')
                     ->get();
```

Check my [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60019662/how-to-use-a-resource-collection-toarray-and-db-without-eloquent/60023033#60023033) here.

Comment: thanks, TsaiKoga.  is it possible return stdClass with row query ?

Comment: @MHFuad I think you can rewrite the` collection` or `toarray` method, but not recommend it.